# Can we PLay Youtube audio only inside app?

Tags: ios, ios7

I am working on an app, where I am required to play the youtube's Audio and Video as well.

I am able to PLay video Using "XCDYouTubeVideoPlayerViewController" available on cocoa controls. (I am getting Youtube url from the backend)

Is there any way , where I can play audio also only inside my app. Because I checked over Internet and stackoverflow, but Couldn't find anything working.

And Is there any way, where the Video or audio can be played at the Back gorund , i.e when I press Home button the vidoe/audio keeps on playing.

All I fund on stack overflow is, that its forbidden, and the chances are your app will be blocked.

Please help, Thanks Again.

Comment: You could probably alloc/init this XCDYouTubeVideoPlayerViewController, but don't push it to Your navigationViewcontroller stack and don't add it's view as a subview. Then simply add Your custom view, with a custom slider, custom play/next/previous/pause buttons which would work with invisible XCDYouTubeVideoPlayerViewController to get current progress values, be able to send play/pause/stop/next/previous commands to XCDYouTubeVideoPlayerViewController.

Answer (score 2):

Youtube doesn't encourage audio only! here's what they have to say about this.

Your API Client will not, and You will not encourage or create functionality for Your users or other third parties to: "separate, isolate, or modify the audio or video components of any YouTube audiovisual content made available through the YouTube API" -Kuan Yong, YouTube API Team

However there's a hacky workaround workaround whereby you can use a hidden UIWebView and play in that.